# How do I get checkbox value to be used in another function?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget that displays a checkbox. The checkboxes display days of the week.
I am curious to know how I can use the values below in another function?
For example, how can I know in another function what the user has selected in terms of a week day?

Here is my checkbox widget code:

```
  bool monVal = false;
  bool tuVal = false;
  bool wedVal = false;
  bool thurVal = false;
  bool friVal = false;
  bool satVal = false;
  bool sunVal = false;

  Widget checkbox(String title, bool boolValue) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(title),
        Checkbox(
          value: boolValue,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            /// manage the state of each value
            setState(() {
              switch (title)
              {
                case "Mon":
                  monVal = value;
                  print(value);
                  break;
                case "Tu":
                  tuVal = value;
                  print(value);
                  break;
                case "Wed":
                  wedVal = value;
                  print(value);

                  break;
                case "Thur":
                  thurVal = value;
                  print(value);

                  break;
                case "Fri":
                  friVal = value;
                  print(value);

                  break;
                case "Sat":
                  satVal = value;
                  print(value);

                  break;
                case "Sun":
                  sunVal = value;
                  print(value);

                  break;
              }
            });
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

the print(value) is pointless.. I just tried that to see if I could get the day of the week selected, but its only going to return true or false.

Here is the code that I use to display the checkboxes.

```
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            checkbox("Mon", monVal),
                            checkbox("Tu", tuVal),
                            checkbox("Wed", wedVal),
                            checkbox("Thur", thurVal),
                            checkbox("Fri", friVal),
                            checkbox("Sat", satVal),
                            checkbox("Sun", sunVal),

                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

Answer to your edited post:

```
static String sun = "Sun";
static String mon = "Mon";
static String tue = "Tue";
static String wed = "Wed";

Map<String, bool> days = {
  sun: false,
  mon: false,
  tue: false,
  wed: false,
}; // global variable

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        checkbox(sun, days[sun]),
        checkbox(mon, days[mon]),
        checkbox(tue, days[tue]),
        checkbox(wed, days[wed]),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget checkbox(String title, bool boolValue) {
  return Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(title),
      Checkbox(
        value: boolValue,
        onChanged: (value) => setState(() => days[title] = value),
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have learnt a lot. I will add your name in the credits of my app. Its a free app anyway. I'm trying to help out a friend with his business.

Comment: @Kiro777 How sweet of you. But I don't need that. Thanks for showing such a friendly gesture.

Comment: I would honestly give you royalties, but not only is the app free, all the code came from people who just left it lying around on the net. haha.. no no.. im kidding. I wrote a lot of it myself. But the community has been very helpful. Its for a friend of mine who has a business..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track multiple days, you can use `Map<String, bool>` like:

```
Map<String, bool> days = {}; // global variable
```

And your function like:

```
Widget checkbox(String title, bool boolValue) {
  return Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(title),
      Checkbox(
        value: boolValue,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          boolValue = value; // forgot to add this
          setState(() => days[title] = value);
        },
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Now you can simply use

```
bool isMondayChecked = days["Mon"];
```

Comment: thanks, I'm trying this out, but now the checkbox doesn't keep its tick. Before, with the switch method, the checkboxes could be checked and unchecked. Now, nothing appears.

Comment: Ops, I forgot to add one line. Check out the updated code.

Comment: Actually that didn't change anything. the checkbox doesn't become checked.(or unchecked).

Comment: Ok I found out the problem your code logic isn't correct actually. It actually makes it a new question.

Comment: Hi, I updated my code. That's how I display the actual checkbox

Comment: lol..haha. OK.. im cool with that,  but what is the question I need to ask? haha. You are a great guy. thank you.

Comment: I added final solution for you. Check it out now.